# Swift: how to convert array of Int into array of Characters?

Tags: ios, swift

for instance I have an array of `Int`:

```
let digits = [Int](0...9)
```

Can I convert this to array of Characters: `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]`?

Swift doesn't implicitly convert types so this doesn't work:

```
let digits: Array<Character> = [Int](0...9)
```

Note: only 0-9 valid, digits could be unsorted.

Comment: why you downvote this question, please describe what's wrong with it?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it means that someone concluded that "This question does not show any research effort" or that "it is unclear or not useful". You can forestall down-votes in the future by demonstrating what research you've done. Also, this is a tad unclear (is it the converting from `Int` to `Character` that you had a problem with or the how to do repeat this across the array of `Int`?). But, I'm with you, that I wish people were more forthcoming regarding their specific concerns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Array(0...9).map({String($0)}).map({ Character($0) })
```

In the **code** above, we are taking each `Int` from `[Int]`, transform it into `String` using the String constructor/initializer (in order words we're applying the String initializer **(a function that takes something and returns a string)** to your `[Int]` using `map` an higher order function), once the first operation is over we'd get `[String]`, the second operation uses this new `[String]` and transform it to `[Character]`.

if you wish to read more on string visit [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string).

> @LeoDabus proposes the following:

```
 Array(0...9).map(String.init).map(Character.init)  //<-- no need for closure
```

Or instead of having two operations just like we did earlier, you can do it with a single iteration.

`Array(0...9).map({Character("\($0)")})`

> @Alexander proposes the following

```
Array((0...9).lazy.map{ String($0) }.map{ Character($0) })

(0...9).map{ Character(String($0)) } //<-- where you don't need an array, you'd use your range right away
```

Comment: `map(String.init).map(Character.init)` or with a single iteration `map({Character("\($0)")})`

Comment: oh ok @LeoDabus

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: if you pass integers above 9 and below 0 - Fatal error: Can't form a Character from a String containing more than one extended grapheme cluster

Comment: So this answer isn't better than mine. Moreover my code is shorter.

Comment: There's no need (and it is wasteful) to make an array out of the range `0...9`. You can just do: `(0...9).map{ String($0) }.map{ Character($0) }`

Comment: Better yet: `Array((0...9).lazy.map{ String($0) }.map{ Character($0) })`, or just: `(0...9).map{ Character(String($0)) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus I've added your code to the answer and give you credit for it

Comment: @Alexander I've added your code to the answer and give you credit for it

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes yes I was going to add some explanations but something came up

Comment: I wrote about "Fatal error" because @LeoDabus said "Note that this would be limited to single digit Array of integers. So this will crash if you pass integers above 9 and below 0" under my answer, and after that my answer was unchecked and answer of Lamar was checked as right. But Lamar answer is not better than mine, it is even worse because code has two maps (it is longer). Now i see that Lamar added code of LeoDabus and Alexander and didn't add mine. Probably, this is because Lamar is offended that my answer was initially marked as correct and that I wrote a comment about Fatal error.

Comment: @ascentman please read my comment and decide whose answer should be marked.

Comment: @yakovlevvl I am and was not offended, I don't see the need of restating your answer since it was not a `comment` under any posts.  Happy Holiday

Answer (score 4):

```
func convertArray(array: [Int]) -> [Character] {
    return array.map {
        Character(String($0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this would be limited to single digit Array of integers. So this will crash if you pass integers above 9 and below 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var arrChars = [string]()

 for i in 0..<digits.count
 {

    let item = digits[i]

    arrChars.append("\(item)")

 }
```

Comment: the same comment above applies to this

Comment: character means single digit , what will make a difference between if it is a one character or a single value in a string like we did

Comment: Array of Chracter it is not the same as Array of String

Comment: I know , but what the difference in implementation

Comment: Maybe the OP wants an array of Strings but he said array of Characters

Comment: @Sh_Khan They are different types, even if related under the hood. It's important to choose the right type and stick to it because Swift will not forgive you if you use them interchangeably

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map) function:

```
let stringArray = digits.map{String($0)}
```

Comment: This isn't an array of characters. Btw you could just pass the String initializer to map. No closure needed. `map(String.init)`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to create the `Character` from Ascii codes.

```
let charArrFromAscii = Array(48...57).map({ Character(UnicodeScalar($0)) })
```

Another way is to map the `Int` value to a `Character`.

```
let charArrFromInt = Array(0...9).map({ Character("\($0)") })
```